# Image placeholder being used when image is uploaded

Tags: product, image

I have a few products that have images uploaded but it only shows the placeholder image in the product page. You can see this at http://www.dananncrafts.com/valentines-offers/jewellery/necklace/handmade-silver-pendant-and-chain-reticulated-texture-925-sterling-silver.html

When you look at the admin for this product you can see that the images are set up correctly as seen in the image below:

[image: Danann image placeholder]

What is going on here? I am very confused as most other products display images as expected.

EDIT: I have tried flushing the caches and have not touched the media.phtml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your php memory limit is low, this will not allow big image to be resized.

Try to increase it in `.htaccess` to higher value

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Comment: Yeah it is the image size...Thanks for that. I can't change the memory limit so just resizing the images is the way forward. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help).